# JQuery Resizable implementation is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to implement JQueryUI resizable. It's not working below is my tentative demo which I will implement later in actual code. Please help me to solve it. It's not working.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    .ui-resizable-helper { border: 1px dotted gray; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        //var a = $("#resizable").html();
        //alert(a);
        $("#resizable").resizable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo-frame">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <div class="demo">  
        <div class="ui-widget-content ui-resizable" id="resizable">
            <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: are your link tag in head section properly connecting jquery ? what happened when you alert(a)?

Comment: That commented alert gave me html content inside tag... So I think linking is ok.

Comment: ok, are you sure about html pattern which needs to be there when u are going to use .resizeable(). i mean i used .accordion couple of days ago and i found out that i have to provide html in way .accordion expects

Comment: Can you please copy-paste whole code to one html file at your end? I am trying to debug this code with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the divs you have inside of your div that seem to be causing an issue.  I commented them on on this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ta9N4/ and it appears to be working fine.

Comment: its resizing vertically, how to resize horizantly, i dont know about it, asking for practices pupose, anyway you answer is accurate

Comment: well. no, you do not.  But I find it better to include there styles from the ones I generate on jQuery's theme generator, and then overwrite the ones I want changed on a separate file added afterwards.  Saves a lot of work when they have a bunch of styles already built out for you.

Answer (score 2):

The method `resizable()` comes from jQuery UI API.
And you didn't include jQueryUI in your html page.
Go [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) to download it (or grab a link to this file), and include it like you did for jQuery (`<script>` tag).